# Cannot find reference System

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference, visual-studio-2017, system

So I use Visual Studio 2017 and everything worked ok. But then I updated to 15.6.0 and suddenly nothing is working anymore.

All the references like Systme.* or Microsoft.* are with a yellow warning sign...

At every project - even new ones- I keep getting the same type of erros after (re)building:

```
The "ResolveAssemblyReference" task could not be initialized with its input parameters

The "ResolveAssemblyReference" task could not be initialized with its input parameters      

The "FindDependenciesOfExternallyResolvedReferences" parameter is not supported by the "ResolveAssemblyReference" task. Verify the parameter exists on the task, and it is a settable public instance property          

This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them
```

I have tried reinstalling Visual Studio 2017, reinstalling .NET Framework, but I **still** get these type of errors on **every** C# project...

Is there any solution, next to completely reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Try to reinstall NuGet

Comment: Are you using SimpleStubs? See https://github.com/Microsoft/SimpleStubs/issues/39

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Community edit (Nick's comment below - an important warning):

> It is dangerous and totally unsupported to overwrite parts of MSBuild 15.6 with parts of MSBuild 15.5. All sorts of other things could break.

---

Finally fixed it!

This file got corrupted somehow through the update to 15.6.0:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\EnterpriseWMSBuild\15.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`

or

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets`

Replace that file with the previous version, and that fixed all the errors!

Get the previous version from a co-worker who hasn't updated their Visual Studio yet.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, it works! I was pulling my hair on this too. Microsoft really needs to get their s*** together and stop breaking something every release...

Comment: And just where does one get this "one from the previous version"?

Comment: @Valuator from a colleague running not the latest version :-)

Comment: This fixed building with Visual Studio for me. I can no longer build from the command line with `msbuild`

Comment: @Mason Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Build.Logging.ProfilerLogger' from assembly 'Microsoft.Build, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
   at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParameters()
   at System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.ToString(TraceFormat traceFormat)

Comment: Here is where you can find the 15.5 version : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Microsoft/msbuild/vs15.5/src/Tasks/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

Comment: It is dangerous and totally unsupported to overwrite parts of MSBuild 15.6 with parts of MSBuild 15.5. All sorts of other things could break.See my comment linking to SimpleStubs. If you are using that, pick up a newer version with a fix.